# have image only show in certain boxes of container

Tags: css, reactjs, z-index

I have a container like so: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7TPP.png)

I have an image that is 100% width and height of the container, but I want the contents to only be visible in the blue boxes and not visible in the red boxes. How do I do so?

Comment: Please edit your question and post your html and css so far.  Try and use the snippet tool (just above the edit box) **<>**.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this with a fixed image is to have each of the boxes have a pseudo before element that is the full size of the container and with that image as background.

In this snippet the box is clipped to its own size so that background gets clipped too and you see just the part that is 'below' the box.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.container>div::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container>div {
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}

.box1 {
  top: 10%;
  height: 70%;
  width: 20%;
  left: 10%;
}

.box2 {
  top: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  left: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, how do I understand the polygon and what the numbers mean in it?

Comment: The numbers are % x and y values (% of the element dimensions width and height). So it's cutting off the bits of the pseudo element that we don't want to see. MDN is a reliable source for info on CSS.