# CSS: element that only visible above certain elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possibe by any way to make element that only can be visible above certain other elements?

For example, in this code, I would like the `.reflection` element to be visible only above the `.reflective` elements (which are at the top and bottom) and not visible on the `.non-reflective` element (which is in the center):

```css
  .bg
  {
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: green;
  }
  .reflective
  {
      width: 100%;
      background-image: url(https://sample.wdd.co.il/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2024/01/mahogany-4.jpg);
      height: 45px;
      margin: 2.5px 0;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
  }
  .non-reflective
  {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: transparent;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid brown;
      border-radius: 15px;
  }
  .reflection
  {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      width: 250px;
      height: 150px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <div class="reflective"></div>
    <div class="non-reflective"></div>
    <div class="reflective"></div>
    <div class="reflection"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using `z-index` property combined with the `position` property.
Also you have to add another `non-reflective-inner` to solve the reflection don't show on outside or the border

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}

.reflective {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://sample.wdd.co.il/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2024/01/mahogany-4.jpg);
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
}

.non-reflective {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 2.5px 0;
}

.non-reflective-inner {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.reflection {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <div class="reflective"></div>
    <div class="non-reflective">
      <div class="non-reflective-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="reflective"></div>
    <div class="reflection"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does the reverse of what is required - ie the reflection is seen only through non-reflective (and that is because the non-reflective element is transparent).

Comment: @sevi I edited the answer, Please check it and let me know if this works.
This fix will solve the issue you have in @A Haworth's answer

Comment: @Jai248 part of the trick that you remved margin from the .reflective, thus it seems like the reflection is not visible above the background.

Comment: @Sevi this is what you wanted right ?

Comment: @Jai248 no. its not "only" can be visible above certain other elements.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help, portio of image. background-position

```css
 .bg {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: green;
        margin: 50px 0;
      }
      .bg2 {
        position: relative;
        background-image: url(https://sample.wdd.co.il/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2024/01/mahogany-4.jpg);
        background-size: 300px 150px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 50px 0;
      }
      .reflective {
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url(https://sample.wdd.co.il/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2024/01/mahogany-4.jpg);
        background-size: 300px 150px;
        height: 45px;
        margin: 2.5px 0;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
        background-position: 0 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .reflective div {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
        border-radius: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
      }
      .reflective2 {
        background-position: 0 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .reflective2 div{
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
        margin-top: -100px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
      }
      .non-reflective {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: transparent;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid brown;
        border-radius: 15px;
        z-index: 10;
        position: relative;
      }
      .reflection {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        width: 250px;
        height: 150px;
      }
```

```html
<p>portion of picture</p>
    <div class="bg">
      <div class="reflective"><div></div></div>
      <div class="non-reflective"></div>
      <div class="reflective reflective2"><div></div></div>
      <div class="reflection"></div>
    </div>
    <p>the whole picture</p>
    <div class="bg2"></div>
```

Comment: this is an example of an idea if you thought like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73693721/have-image-only-show-in-certain-boxes-of-container